# JQuery complicated selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Should be easy. I'm adding a button to each table row, that gets information out of a number of table cells in that row.

```
<tr>
  <td><img src='targetInfo' /></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <div>CLICKED ELEMENT</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I would expect:

`this: $(this).closest('tr td:eq(0) img').attr('src');` or

`this: $(this).closest('tr>td:eq(0)>img').attr('src');`

to work, but neither is working properly.

Currently I'm having to use the below, which seems sub-optimal. What am I missing in my selector?

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').children('img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current working solution is the best approach (or something similar to it, such as):

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0) > img').attr('src');
```

For this problem you won't be able to avoid having to crawl up the tree and then back down. Several ways to accomplish that, but not within a single selector.

Comment: Was worried it might be. I tried that solution, but got undefined as the result. I would think it works looking at it, but something is not right.

Comment: Hmm... staring at it some more I can't see anything glaringly wrong. I'd be happy to take a stab at a jsfiddle of it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).find('img').attr('src');
```

or:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').find('img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar recently. I just used parent and first-child.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child img').attr('src')
```

Comment: The only issue would be, the TR is not the direct parent of the DIV. The selector must start with .closest to climb up the chain and find the first TR

Comment: Ah, absolutely correct. Totally missed that the click was from within a nested div. I was making all cells in the row clickable. Sorry!